# Where should log4j.properties be located when using Maven Exec Plugin?

Tags: maven-2, configuration, log4j

I am trying to use log4j in a project I am executing with the exec-maven-plugin.  I have tried placing the file in the following locations:

```
$PROJECT_HOME
$PROJECT_HOME/src/main/resources
$PROJECT_HOME/target
$PROJECT_HOME/target/classes
```

For all locations of the file, I am getting the following message when executing the code:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (mypacakge.MyClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Where should the `log4j.properties` file be located?

---

exec-maven-plugin config:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>mypackage.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: Could you append your `exec-maven-plugin` configuration.

Comment: What execution phase is the exec plug-in bound to?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. Put the property file under

./src/main/resources/log4j.xml

1. You can specify it from the command line:

$ mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=com.lei.java.sample.Test  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.xml

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the right way (because I don't know this plugin), but you may use the configuration of the plugin to specify to the classpath of the VM the right location of your file  :

```
<configuration>
   <executable>maven</executable>
   <!-- optional -->
   <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
   <arguments>
       <argument>-classpath</argument>
       <argument>/path/to/dirthatcontainslog4J</argument>
      ...
   </arguments>
</configuration>
```

What is the purpose of using such a plugin ? 
If this is in order to test your app, you should probably use maven-dependency-plugin : http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-custom-packaged.html

You can find more info here :
[maven jar-with-dependencies log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689619/maven-jar-with-dependencies-log4j)

[How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Actually, log4j has provided command line option support for locating configuration file manually. However it is used for `java` command itself, and you could use it in Maven building through `-Dexec.args` option to pass java options directly:

```
$ mvn -Dexec.args="-Dlog4j.configurationFile='./log4j2.xml' -classpath /previously/configured/path" org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
```

Besides, arguments in `exec.args` could also be written persistently into Mojo's `<arguments>` section, [as said in document](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#arguments):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <executions>
    ...
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>maven</executable>
    <arguments>
      <argument>-Dlog4j.configurationFile="./log4j2.xml"</argument>
      ...
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```