# maven jar-with-dependencies log4j

Tags: maven, log4j

I'm building an executable jar-with-dependencies using maven. My application uses log4j and there's an appropriate log4j.properties file under src/resources.

My problem is that there are other log4j.properties files floating around so when maven builds the jar-with-dependencies, it's grabbing one of those instead of the one I want it to, and skipping any others it finds due to log4j.properties already being included.

Anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation of jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html), it is a very blunt instrument. For better control, use the maven-shade-plugin, where you can exclude all those unwanted files.